# tensorflow: how to use flags.DEFINE_multi_float()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use bash code to run a python file with lots of parameters. like:

```
python "${WORK_DIR}"/eval.py \
  --logtostderr \
  --eval_split="val" \
  --model_variant="xception_65" \
  --atrous_rates=6 \
  --atrous_rates=12 \
  --atrous_rates=18 \
  --output_stride=16 \
  --decoder_output_stride=4 \
  --eval_crop_size="513,513" \
  --checkpoint_dir="${TRAIN_LOGDIR}" \
  --eval_logdir="${EVAL_LOGDIR}" \
  --dataset_dir="${PASCAL_DATASET}" \
  --max_number_of_evaluations=1 \
  --eval_scales=[0.5,0.25,1.75]
```

But then I got error:

> absl.flags._exceptions.IllegalFlagValueError: flag
>   --eval_scales=[0.5,0.25,1.75]: could not convert string to float: '[0.5,0.25,1.75]'

**So what is the right format** to pass parameter to variable defined by `flags.DEFINE_multi_float()`

```
# Change to [0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75] for multi-scale test.
flags.DEFINE_multi_float('eval_scales', [1.0],
                         'The scales to resize images for evaluation.')
```

Answer (score 0):

for multi float you should define your parameters length(your-list) times.

if you have a list like this [0.5,0.25], you should define --eval_scales 2 times for each value present into your list:

--eval_scales=0.5

--eval_scales=0.25